# How do I add an array of elements in MongoDB to an array in an existing document?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In MongoDB, I'm trying to write a query to add elements from an array to an existing document, but instead of adding the elements as objects:

```
property: ObjectID(xxx)
```

the elements are getting added as just

```
ObjectID(xxx)
```

Forgive me if I get the terminology wrong.  I'm completely new to MongoDB; I normally only work with relational databases.  How do I properly add these new elements?

I have a collection called auctions which has two fields: ID and properties.  Properties is an array of objects named property.  Here's an example with two auction documents:

** I changed the object IDs to make them easier to reference in our discussion

```
Collection db.auctions
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("abc"),
    "properties" : [
        {
            "property" : ObjectId("prop1")
        }, 
        {
            "property" : ObjectId("prop2")
        }, 
        {
            "property" : ObjectId("prop3")
        }]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("def"),
    "properties" : [
        {
            "property" : ObjectId("prop97")
        }, 
        {
            "property" : ObjectId("prop98")
        }]
}
```

I want to add 3 new properties to auction "abc".  How do I do this?

Here's is what I tried:

I have an array of properties that looks like this:

```
Array PropsToAdd
[
    ObjectId("prop4"), 
    ObjectId("prop5"), 
    ObjectId("prop6")
]
```

I wrote an update query to push these properties into the properties array in auctions:

```
db.auctions.update(
    {"_id": "abc"}
    ,
    { $push: { properties: { $each: PropsToAdd } } } 
);
```

This query gave the result below.  Notice that instead of adding elements named property with a value from my array, it's just added my values from my array.  I obviously need to add that "property" part, but how do I do that?

```
Collection db.auctions (_id "abc" only)
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("abc"),
    "properties" : [
        {
            "property" : ObjectId("prop1")
        }, 
        {
            "property" : ObjectId("prop2")
        }, 
        {
            "property" : ObjectId("prop3")
        }, 
        ObjectId("prop4"), 
        ObjectId("prop5"), 
        ObjectId("prop6"), 
        ObjectId("prop7")]
}
```

The result I'm looking for is this:

```
Collection db.auctions (_id "abc" only)
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("abc"),
    "properties" : [
        {
            "property" : ObjectId("prop1")
        }, 
        {
            "property" : ObjectId("prop2")
        }, 
        {
            "property" : ObjectId("prop3")
        }, 
        {
            "property" : ObjectId("prop4")
        },
        {
            "property" : ObjectId("prop5")
        },         
        {
            "property" : ObjectId("prop6")
        } 
}
```

Here is some further information on that array of properties I'm adding.  I get it from running these queries.  Perhaps one of them needs changed?

This query gets an array of current properties:

```
var oldActiveProperties = db.properties.distinct( "saleNumber", { "active": true, "auction": ObjectId("abc") } );
```

Then those results are used to find properties in the new file that weren't in the old file:

```
var PropsToAdd = db.newProperties.distinct(
    "_id"
    , { "saleNumber": { "$nin": oldActiveProperties }, "active": true}
);
```

The resulting array is what I need to add to the auctions collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the JavaScript's native **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** method to map the array into an array of documents. The following shows this:

```
var PropsToAdd = db.newProperties.distinct("_id", 
    { "saleNumber": { "$nin": oldActiveProperties }, "active": true}
).map(function (p) { return { property: p }; });

db.auctions.update(
    {"_id": "abc"},
    { $push: { "properties": { "$each": PropsToAdd } } } 
);
```

Comment: That worked great; thank you!  Like I said, I'm new to MongoDB.  I'm using MongoChef to write queries.  Are most/all JavaScript functions available to me in writing queries?

Comment: MongoDB uses the JavaScript engine [SpiderMonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey) for both the [mongo](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/#bin.mongo) shell and for server-side javascript in [mongod](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/#bin.mongod) so the api is available when writing your queries in mongo shell although most interactions with MongoDB do not use JavaScript but use an [idiomatic driver](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/drivers/) in the language of the interacting application.